# Creating Subdomains on Amazon EC2 & Route53

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, subdomain, amazon-route53

I feel like this should be infinitely easier than it is, but here we are in 2016 and Apache still makes configuration arcane. What I want is to simply host a sub-domain in a different directory than the main site. Here is more or less what I have now:

```
# Start of httpd.conf file
# Some crap
# Some <Directory> crap (this should be clearer from Apache)
#

<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/mainsite"
  ServerName www.mycomp.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/blog"
  ServerName blog.mycomp.com
</VirtualHost>

# End of httpd.conf file
```

However, when I restart httpd, only the blog.mycomp.com URL works, while the default one (www), throws a 500 server error. Both the **www** and **blog** subdomains have **A** records in Route53 that point to the ElasticIP, and both resolve so its not a DNS issue. The funny thing is when I remove the blog `<VirtualHost>`, it works fine. I've narrowed it down to the DocumentRoot line, but cannot figure out why I cannot get 2 (or more) subdomains serving from different folders on my server.

Can someone please explain why one domain works and the other doesn't, and what I need to do in order to fix? Thanks!

Comment: not sure, but check for security groups

Comment: Have you enabled www in domain control pannel , like if just have abc.com domain , you have to add www so that www.abc.com works like blog.abc.com works ?

Comment: Yes - www is enabled. I'm trying to point blog.abc.com to a different directory in my filesystem. I am able to get the blog subdomain to work, but when I do that it kills the main domain.